# Firebase doesn't create child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[hash tag code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RSCn.png)    [DB reference and main hashTag child creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVIgT.png)   [Entisipated Result: HashTag is the new child in the DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvPFB.png)I am currently working on my iOS app, which uses Firebase as a backend service. The problem is, that when I want to add a child to the main database (e.g. one so called, main child) it doesn't work. I used this:

```
var REF_HASHTAG = Database.database().reference().child("hashTag")
```

I used the same setup for the commenting system and it didn't have the same issue.

Then in another file, I have the following:

```
    for var word in words {
        if word.hasPrefix("#") {
            word = word.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters)
            let newHashTagRef = API.HashTag.REF_HASHTAG.child(word.lowercased())
            newHashTagRef.updateChildValues([newPostId: true])
        }
    }
```

Also, when I try to add it manually, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Four things: 1) include what you want your Firebase structure to look like. That will help us understand what the desired result is 2) what is *newPostId*? 3) if you add a statement right after the *let newHashTagRef* line that says *print(newHashTagRef)* what does it print 4) Are you authenticated when this code runs?

Comment: @Jay I have added links to pictures in my question, hopefully you can see them. As you can see the anticipated result is hashTag child which contains the hashTag word as a sub-child. Then this word sub-child contains the newPostId, which is reference to the post info(e.g. caption, picture, etc), and true value. But the result observed is that this hashTag child is not created. How can I fix the problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: To get questions answers, you need to help us, help you; I asked 4 questions about the issue and you addressed one of them. Please include enough data in the question for us to answer. For example, you included a pic showing an error, but there's no info as to how that pic ties into your question; that pic is showing a *class HashTagAPI* but nothing in your question uses that class or instantiates it. If you think REF_HASTAG refers to what's in that class, that would be incorrect as your structure is *root/hashTag/baby* and REF_HASHTAG points to hashTag**s** note the 's'. Update the question!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#basic_write) you need to use the `setValue` function. Right now that path has no value, so you'd need that as well. An example would be something like this:

```
var REF_HASHTAG = Database.database().reference().
REF_HASHTAG.setValue("hashTag":"theHashtag")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that in another file i use the following:                                   let newHashTagRef = API.HashTag.REF_HASHTAG.child(word.lowercased())
                newHashTagRef.updateChildValues([newPostId: true])   and it still doesn't work. Any others ideas why it doesn't work

Comment: @Nikkko please take that comment and include it as part of your question so it's more complete. While you're at it, can you clarify what you're trying to do as 'it doesn't work' is super vague. For example, you may not be authenticated so therefore you don't have write access to your database. Are you getting errors? What happens when 'it doesnt work'?

Comment: @Jay  I am making a hashTag feture in my app. It is very similar to the instagram and twitter. After you type the # and some word after it, it shuild save the word after # as a sub-child of it's main child(hashTag), and in the this sub-child it has another sub-child that consists of the newPostId and true statement.      P.S. I think i added the note to the question